# wso2 ESB Is it possible to remove a parameter of the url before sending it to the endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

My proxy receives a parameter to take a decision, which I don't want to send the endpoint, how can I remove it before calling the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **URLRewrite** mediator for that. There is a great example in the wso2 library and you can also refer to the wso2 official documentation

http://wso2.com/library/3297/

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/URLRewrite+Mediator

Comment: Thank you! I solve my problem with your recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

In my solution I remove the query when it equals to propName=V1 or propName=V2

```
<inSequence>
     <property name="sw_prop" expression="$url:propName"
               scope="default" type="STRING"/>

     <property name="querystrings" expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>

     <rewrite inProperty="querystrings" outProperty="querystrings">
        <rewriterule>
           <condition>
              <or>
                 <equal type="url" source="query" value="propName=V1"/>
                 <equal type="url" source="query" value="propName=V2"/>
              </or>
           </condition>
           <action type="remove" fragment="query"/>
        </rewriterule>
     </rewrite>

     <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
               expression="get-property('querystrings')"
               scope="axis2"/>

     <switch source="get-property('sw_prop')">
        <case regex="V1">
           <send>
              <endpoint key="EP1"/>
           </send>
        </case>
        <case regex="V2">
           <send>
              <endpoint key="EP2"/>
           </send>
        </case>
        <default>
           <send>
              <endpoint key="AggProxyEP"/>
           </send>
        </default>
     </switch>
</inSequence>
```